# How can I retrieve the nearest values from a column in Kusto Query Language (KQL) based on an input array

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

In my case, I have a more complex query, where I get result log values with corresponding timestamps. I would like to use this result timestamps to get other logged values, with nearby timestamps => different and not synchronized logging systems but related to each other.

With a single timestamp input, I can use the following example to get the nearest timestamp from a example list (in my real case, this should be a list from another query):

```
let required_timestamp = datetime("2023-01-23T15:50:14.2870427Z");
let timestamp_list = range timestamp from datetime("2023-01-23T15:00") to datetime("2023-01-23T16:00") step 1s
| project rand_timestamp = timestamp
| take 100;
timestamp_list
| extend diff = abs(rand_timestamp - required_timestamp)
| top 1 by diff asc
```

How can I use a list or a result of another query as an input to get a list of nearest timestamps, e.g.:

```
let required_timestamp = dynamic([datetime("2023-01-23T15:50:14.2870427Z"), datetime("2023-01-23T15:50:15.2870427Z")]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator).

for example:

```
let candidates = range(datetime(2023-11-09 17:43:37.5858056), datetime(2023-11-10 16:43:37.5858056), 65m);
let my_table = datatable(timestamp:datetime)
[
    datetime(2023-11-10 01:37:44),
    datetime(2023-11-10 02:37:45),
    datetime(2023-11-10 03:37:46)
]
;
my_table
| mv-apply candidate = candidates to typeof(datetime) on (
    extend diff = abs(candidate - timestamp)
)
| top 1 by diff asc
```

| timestamp | candidate | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-10 03:37:46.0000000 | 2023-11-10 03:28:37.5858056 | 00:09:08.4141944 |

Comment: ah ok, and if I'd like to get a "candidate" for all three values, I can set top to 3, right? At least that's what it looks like in adx or is it just a coincidence?